# Conflicting Wargoals

Tags: crusader-kings-2

The HRE asked me to join in their war. I refused and then looked at who they were attacking and I noticed there were trying to claim an independent county somewhere in the Alps (forget the name). So I thought, why not. I found a claimant for the county, invited him to court, gave him a spare city I had and declared war on the same county myself. This made HRE hostile to me because of conflicting wargoals. Fair enough. We ended up fighting each other instead of the county (I eventually snuck one stack in to seige the county and used another to run interference and stop HRE from doing the same).

Later, I noticed BE was waging a holy war against an independent pagan country somewhere around Hungry. So, again, I thought why not and declared my own holy war against the same. But in this case, BE did not become hostile and we both laid siege to the same county (BE occupied 2 of 4 holdings, I took the other 2, but BE ended up winning the war - they had a head start).

So why did I get the hostile due to conflicting war goals in the first case, but not in the second? How can I tell when being opportunist and trying to declare war on a county already at war if I'm going to set off a massive conflict with another neighbor?

Comment: My guess is that the casus belli was the same in the second case.

Comment: @Sconibulus: I'm guessing it must be related to the CB. In the first case HRE had a claim CB and I had a (different) claim CB. In the second case, BE has a holy war and I had a holy war. But since BE is orthodoxy and I am catholic, I would have thought that was different enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The types of casus bellis are in `..\common\cb_types\00_cb_types.txt`. There is a flag `hostile_against_others` that is set for certain CBs and not others. It's not clear to me the exact functionality of this, but the only description I could find states that this flags hostility to all other combatants.

So if the game wants to consider multiple same-religion holy wars to be not conflicting (which makes sense), there is no way for it to consider differing religion holy wars to be conflicting either.

The CB types it is set for are:

- claims
- dejure claims
- invasions
- generated revolts (peasant/etc)
- subjugations/conquests
- **buddhist** holy wars (and only these guys)

Not sure why buddhists are different from the rest.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty straight forward.

In the first case, you declare war on "County", because you have a claim to press. As does the HRE. Your specific war goal is that you both want the county for yourself. Of course, only one of you can achieve that goal, so naturally there is a conflict here. Had you joined their war, you would have fought for their cause – regardless of your claim/claimants in your court.

In the second case, both you and the Byzantine Empire agreed that "Country" needed to be taught a serious lesson. Your war goals are not at conflict, thus you remain neutral/friendly to eachother, as you are working towards the same end.

Simply put, if you are declaring war for a title, you will be hostile to anyone with an ongoing dispute for that title. Should someone else win their dispute and achieve their war goal, all other disputes for that title will automatically end.

Comment: I'm sure that's probably right. In the case with the BE one, I guess we both had the goal of making the county Christian (abet with different flavors) and the different flavor part isn't enough of a difference to make us hostile. I wonder if the same would be true if we were talking Sunni vs Shia? From what I understand (don't have the DLC) they can holy war against each other.

Comment: Alright – I did not know you had a different religion from the Byzantines. This is why it was two separate wars. Your war most likely ended inconclusively, since the target changed religion.

You can declare holy war against anyone that you consider heretic or infidel – unless you are unreformed pagan, or some other special cases. See: http://www.ckiiwiki.com/Casus_Belli#Holy_War

Comment: It did end inconclusively, because they convert to orthodoxy (after BE reach 100% war score), that wasn't really the question. The question was why I wasn't hostile to BE when my goal was to make them Catholic and their goal was to make the Orthodoxy. Apparently those goals aren't considered conflicting.